# Use pandas DataFrame / Panel .apply() together with index/column information

Tags: python, pandas, apply

I have a pandas DataFrame that looks like this:

```
           2016      2017      2018      2019      2020
1  0.014199  0.020776  0.016393  0.010112  0.013346
2  0.025220  0.024088  0.035357  0.026878  0.031841
3  0.016345  0.014117  0.017157  0.019280  0.017307
4  0.021467  0.020389  0.027269  0.027727  0.025750
5  0.012459  0.004377  0.015435  0.023725  0.031228
```

And a function that looks like this:

```
def f(a,b):
   return a+b
```

I am looking for a fast (i.e., avoiding loops) way of calculating f for every element in the dataframe with `a` being the entry and `b` its column name (or index, if that also works).

Output would then look like this:

```
    2016             2017
1   2016.014199      2017.020776 ...
2   2016.025220      2017.024088 ...
```

I have been trying the .apply() functionality but haven't found out how to make it work. Do you have any tips?

KR, Richard

Comment: Thanks, just what I was looking for. Will also experiment with other operations (such as multiplication and taking powers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
In [138]: df.apply(lambda x: int(x.name) + x)
Out[138]:
          2016         2017         2018         2019         2020
1  2016.014199  2017.020776  2018.016393  2019.010112  2020.013346
2  2016.025220  2017.024088  2018.035357  2019.026878  2020.031841
3  2016.016345  2017.014117  2018.017157  2019.019280  2020.017307
4  2016.021467  2017.020389  2018.027269  2019.027727  2020.025750
5  2016.012459  2017.004377  2018.015435  2019.023725  2020.031228
```

**NOTE: @root's solution is much faster:**

```
In [150]: df = pd.concat([df] * 10**5, ignore_index=False)

In [151]: df.shape
Out[151]: (500000, 5)

In [152]: %timeit df.apply(lambda x: int(x.name) + x)
10 loops, best of 3: 40.7 ms per loop

In [153]: %timeit df.add(df.columns.map(int))
100 loops, best of 3: 7.95 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your column names are integers you can use [`add`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add.html) with the column values:

```
df = df.add(df.columns.values)
```

If the column names are strings, use `map` to convert the column names to integers when using `add`:

```
df = df.add(df.columns.map(int))
```

Comment: I like your solution more than mine. ;) `df.add(df.columns.map(int))` - this will work also with strings

Comment: Thanks!  I was just testing out `map` but you beat me to it with your comment.  Then I was about to do timings but you beat me to that too!